# facebook sdk authorization on multiple pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();
            auth.Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me" };

            if (auth.Authorize())
            { get needed data...
```

If i place this code in default.aspx (Page_Load method), it works fine.
If I place this in a viewscore.aspx  (Page_Load method), Authorize() returns false.
I get to viewscore.aspx by using a link from default.aspx, nothing special.  Why is this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but doesn't Facebook allow canvas authorization only on page which has been given as a Canvas URL?

Comment: This means that I save the authorization token in a cookie and reuse it on other pages, or how do you work?

Comment: I usually just save authorization token in a database. Don't save it in a cookie (as this could result in serious trouble in case of cookie hijacking). You can use Session though.

Comment: And how do you keep track of the user? Do you use cookies to keep this information as he navigates from page to page?

Comment: I put his session ID into a cookie and insert his session data (including token) into database, indexed by this ID. Each time user navigates to page, this data is loaded back from database and used to talk to FB and do other stuff. But AFAIK, ASP has it's own session mechanism, so you don't really need to care about database and cookie-related stuff.